# Combining Gradle with Ivy and sources for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gradle, ivy

We use Gradle to build our projects and to manage our dependencies. We want to reuse our legacy Ivy repository which is filesystem based. Our convention was to have several artifacts per module - one of them being a source artifact.

The normal jars are perfectly managed by the Gradle Eclipse integration. But we are not shown the source artifacts. Are there any conventions for this kind of setting, e.g. name of the source artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

`artifactName-sources.jar` should work, as should defining a configuration named `sources` (and assigning sources artifacts to that configuration) in the `iyy.xml`.